# Finding all roots of an equation in Python

Tags: python, function, scipy

I have a function that I want to find its roots. I could write a program to figure out its roots but the point is, each time that I want to find the other root I should give it an initial value manually which I do not want to do that. I want to have all the roots in a list since I want to do some operations on the roots after finding them. This is my code:

```
import math
import scipy
import scipy.optimize
c = 5
alambda = 1
rho = 0.8
b = rho * c / alambda
def f(zeta):
    y = ((zeta**c)*(math.exp((alambda*b)*(1-zeta)))) - 1
    return y

print scipy.optimize.newton(f,  -1)
```

Comment: No algorithm can calculate all roots of a function, except for functions with some special structure (eg. polynomial etc.). For your function, it appears the roots can be related to the Lambert W function.

Comment: Indeed, I will second @pv.'s comment. You need to use some smarts about the function (and there is some literature out there on being smarter), but ultimately you are, to some sense, doomed, even if you know that all the roots are real.  If they could be complex, well, life gets even harder...

Answer (score 0):

For integer `c`, the roots of the function are given by the Lambert W function, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

```
from numpy import exp, pi
from scipy.special import lambertw
c = 3
alambda = 1.234
rho = 0.8
b = rho * c / alambda
def f(zeta):
    y = ((zeta**c)*(exp((alambda*b)*(1-zeta)))) - 1
    return y
def zeta_root(k, n):
    a = alambda
    return -c/(a*b) * lambertw(-a*b/c * exp(-(a*b+2j*pi*n)/c), k=k)
for k in range(-20, 20):
    # also n can be any integer; probably reproduces the same root set
    # as varying k
    zeta = zeta_root(k, 3)
    print("k={0}, zeta={1}, error={2}".format(k, zeta, abs(f(zeta))))
```

The equation has an infinite number of complex-valued roots. The `k=0` and `k=-1` roots which correspond to real branches of the Lambert W function may be real-valued.

For non-integer `c` the situation seems a bit more complicated due to the extra branch cut, although at least the real-valued positive roots should be captured.

Comment: Suppose I have my own code and I want to calculate the complex roots with giving initial values. Is it possible? And suppose I am only interested in the roots which their magnitude is less than one.

Comment: Why do you want to calculate the solutions giving initial values, when you have the analytical solution to the problem? As to your second question: look up properties of the Lambert W function and try to work it out.

Comment: I do not know why you use Lambert W function since according to the Rouche's theorem the above-mentioned function is a polynomial.

Comment: You wrote above the equation `zeta^c exp(a*b - a*b*zeta) - 1 = 0`. This is not a polynomial equation. If you have a different equation, please write it correctly.

Comment: Sorry for late answer. According to Rouch's Theorem the above-mentioned equation will be considered as a polynomial equation.

Comment: For c=a=1, b=-1, the equation is the definition of W(e). What you are claiming is incorrect.