# Plotting an intersection when graph touches an x-axis

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

So I'm making a Graphical Calculator, which shows an intersection between graphs and axes. I found the method from [Intersection of two graphs in Python, find the x value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28766692/intersection-of-two-graphs-in-python-find-the-x-value) to work most of the time, however trying to plot the x-axis intersection of `x**2` as such

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.01)
g = (x) ** 2

plt.plot(x, g, '-')

idx = np.argwhere(np.diff(np.sign(g))).flatten()
plt.plot(x[idx], g[idx], 'ro')
plt.show()
```

doesn't put the dot at `(0,0)` point. I assumed it has something to do with the fact that `0` is not in `g`, so the grpah it doesn't actually pass through the point exactly and instead gets really close to it. So I experimented with changing `idx` to

```
epsilon = 0.0001
# or another real small number
idx = g < epsilon
```

Unfortunately, that only seemed to make a lot of points near the actual x-intercept, instead of just one.

Answer (score 1):

You are close, instead, I just search for where the absolute value of the derivative is at a minimum such that

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.01)
g = x**2


plt.plot(np.abs(np.diff(g)))
plt.show()
```

which shows that the minimum should be at index 500:

[image: result]

Then all you need to do is return the index of the minimum value with `argmin` and plot that point

```
idx = np.argmin(np.abs(np.diff(g)))
plt.plot(x, g, '-')
plt.scatter(x[idx],g[idx])
plt.show()
```

[image: result2]

You'll need to modify the `idx` variable to return multiple roots, but for the question you posted, this should be sufficient.

Comment: I was asking for more general solution. setting g to something like (x-1)^2*x*(x+1)^2 exposes the flaws of this method.

Comment: As I had stated, you'll have to play around with the algorithm to be valid for multiple roots. Root-finding packages exist in the [`scipy.optimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/optimize.html#root-finding) module, so that may be a good place to start. As far as the question you had asked goes, my answer was meant to address it. You may want to open a second question asking for a generalized solution.

Comment: Maybe also take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28724070/finding-all-roots-of-an-equation-in-python) for an explanation why the generalized question you are asking is nontrivial.